# Funcion que devuelve una lista

Tags: c++

Soy nuevo programando en c++; hasta ahora he programado en visual basic.e consigue en estado de 4 entradas analogicas y los guarda en una lista `EA={"","","",""}`. Pero cuando quiero que la funcion devuelva esa lista (`return EA;`) me da un error. Os dejo en codigo por si me podeis ayudar.

He modificado el codigo y casi lo tengo pero me sigue dando un error de conversion:

```
std::tr1::array<int, 4>FuncionEA(){

std::tr1::array<int, 4> EA[]={0,0,0,0};

return EA;}
```

el error es el siguente:

```
Error   1   error C2440: 'return' : no se puede realizar la conversión de 'std::tr1::array<_Ty,_Size> [1]' a 'std::tr1::array<_Ty,_Size>'   c:\users\p\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\we\we\we.cpp   13  we
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Problema.

El error está claro como el cristal, tal vez no estás familiarizado con los mensajes del compilador y por eso no lo entiendes.

El compilador te está diciendo, "*No se puede convertir un arreglo de cuatro `double` (`double [4]`) a un `double`)*".

Evidente ¿verdad?, cuatro coches no son un coche, cuatro tostadas con mantequilla no son una tostada con mantequilla, cuatro gallifantes no es un gallifante... se ve la idea ¿no?.

#### Solución.

Usa [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

```
std::array<double, 4> FuncionEA(){

    // ...

    std::array<double, 4> EA[]={0.,0.,0.,0.};

    while(exitChar != '5')
    {
        for (adcChannel = 0; adcChannel < 4; adcChannel++)
        {
            // ...
            EA[adcChannel]=(temp+0.03)/0.15;
        }
    }

    return EA;
}
```

La plantilla [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) te permite manejar colecciones de datos (en tu caso un `double`) con un tamaño fijo (en tu caso cuatro). Si la sintaxis te resulta molesta, puedes declarar el tipo con un alias:

```
using entradas_analogicas = std::array<double, 4>;

entradas_analogicas FuncionEA(){

    // ...

    entradas_analogicas EA[]={0.,0.,0.,0.};

    // ...

    return EA;
}
```

Ten en cuenta que estás inicializando el `array` con enteros (`0`) pero éste contiene `double`, usa un literal `double`.

Comment: Muchas gracias pero me sigue dando un error; te adjunto el error arriba.Gracias

Comment: Te falta incluir la cabecera [`<array>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: Gracias de nuevo pero no puedo incluirlo: Error 1 fatal error C1083: No se puede abrir el archivo incluir: 'array': No such file or directory c:\Users\P\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Funcion\Funcion\Funcion.cpp 12 Funcion

Comment: Posiblemente tu compilador (aparentemente Visual Studio 2008) es demasiado viejo y podría no disponer de la cabecera a `<array>`, actualiza tu compilador o usa `<vector>`: `typedef std::vector<double> entradas_analogicas;`, pero posiblemente te fallará al inicializar y deberás usar `entradas_analogicas EA(4, 0);`.

Comment: Gracias, tratare de solucionarlo y te cuento.

Comment: Tengo otro error de conversion, pero creo que estoy mas cerca.